# How to pass a value to the variable of android.view.View.OnClickListener in data binding in Android Studio?

Tags: android, data-binding

The following code is from the project [sunflower](https://github.com/android/sunflower).

There is variable named `clickListener`, it's a variable of `android.view.View.OnClickListener`.

I don't know how to pass a value to the variable `clickListener` of `android.view.View.OnClickListener` in data binding in Android Studio, could you tell me?

And more, I can't understand that the code `binding.setClickListener{...}` in PlantAdapter.kt, could you tell me?

**list_item_plant.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="clickListener"
            type="android.view.View.OnClickListener"/>
        ...
    </data>

    <com.google.samples.apps.sunflower.views.MaskedCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
        android:onClick="@{clickListener}"
       
    ...
}
```

**PlantAdapter.kt**

```
class PlantAdapter : ListAdapter<Plant, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(PlantDiffCallback()) {    
    ...
    class PlantViewHolder(
        private val binding: ListItemPlantBinding
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        init {
            binding.setClickListener {
                binding.plant?.let { plant ->
                    navigateToPlant(plant, it)
                }
            }
        }

     ...
}
```

**Added content**

Normally, I define a data binding variable `name` in *plain_activity_solution_2.xml*, I should assign a value for it such as  `binding.name = "Ada"` in *PlainOldActivitySolution2.kt*.

So when I define a data binding variable `clickListener` in *list_item_plant.xml*, I should assign a value for it such as `binding.clickListener=...` in *PlantAdapter.kt*,
But I can't find `binding.clickListener=...` in *PlantAdapter.kt*, instead I only find `binding.setClickListener {...}` , why?

**plain_activity_solution_2.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>    
        <variable
            name="name"
            type="String"/>    
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/plain_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
            android:text="@{name}"
     ...
}
```

**PlainOldActivitySolution2.kt**

```
class PlainOldActivitySolution2 : AppCompatActivity() {

    // Obtain ViewModel from ViewModelProviders
    private val viewModel by lazy { ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SimpleViewModel::class.java) }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val binding: PlainActivitySolution2Binding =
            DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.plain_activity_solution_2)

        binding.name = "Ada"
        binding.lastName = "Lovelace"
       
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: What variable do you want to pass to the onclicklistener?

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how to pass a variable  to clickListener, this is the question I 'm asking.

Comment: Yeah but whats the goal you try to achieve with passing a value to the onClickListener? Is it a variable from your xml file? Is it a variable you want to access inside your ViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what variable you're trying to pass, and why.

But to pass any variable you can use a lambda expression like this:

```
 android:onClick="@{() -> clickListener(someVariable, someOtherVariable)}"
```

If you need the view, you can pass it like that:

```
 android:onClick="@{(view) -> clickListener(view)}"
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: you should always use the set~name_of_your_variable~() method. so, do not use binding.name, use binding.setName().

Comment: @HelloCW this of course means that setClickListener is the correct way to pass that variable. but I suggest you rename your variable to something a little more obvious (like plantClickListener), because setClickListener() might be confused with a clickListener on the layout itself.

Comment: @HelloCW please accept the answer to help other people find it

Answer (score 0):

The `binding` is there own class, normally android `View.OnClickListener` is passing just `Button` as casted `View`, you can't add more, but you can listen with `View.OnClickListener` then find real object and pass to your own listeners.